# CartoDB local installation - how to create users other than development

Tags: carto, server

I have a local install of CartoDB. It all works fine following the instructions at https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb. I manage to create a user called development, and then log in successfully via my browser at http://development.localhost.lan:3000/login as development/development. I can insert data and plot beautiful visualisations.

Now I'd like other people to access this marvellous thing and have their own accounts and data stored there. So for that, I did this:

`sh cartodb/script/create_dev_user newusername newusername newusername newusername@email.com`

This went fine, and created a new empty DB I can see with PgAdmin.

Now if I go to http://development.localhost.lan:3000/login and try to log in as newusername/newusername, I'm redirected to http://newusername.localhost.lan:3000/login, which doesn't exist. I'm not sure why this is happening.

Is there some other configuration I'm missing for the server?

I'm confused about the instructions in the website naming development to both the user and the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer to my own question!

If has an easy fix, fortunately. The URLs to connect to each of the user's dashboards need to be added to the /etc/hosts files. Like so:

```
echo "127.0.0.1 newusername.localhost.lan" | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts
```

That's about it.

Comment: If your question is solved, could you mark it as answered so that the rest of the community can benefit from it? :)